# Using piwik analytics with coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, lucee, mura

I had asked the question in cfml slack channel too.

But i am asking here to get better answer from those who do not have #cfml slack channel joined.

see a mura plugin but i am using a plain coldfusion code, any help appreciated: `https://github.com/Lagaffe/MuraPiwik`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I had not used piwik yet, I am planning to create a website and host piwik and use its API, so i searched for Coldfusion based API rather than rebuilding api for piwik api, i got the mura plugin but i am not using MURA, so i want to know how can i move bits and pieces of the plugin to use only the specific api calls only rather than installing whole mura code and mura code seems to using framework in that plugin, not sure but it looks like